# Paypal Connect Account to use Api instead of using API Keys

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, stripe-payments, paypal-subscriptions

I am using [PHP-Paypal-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) and [stripe-php](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php) for my Saas App such as Shopify.

Users will be able to connect their paypal or stripe account and accept payment from their products.

For now, I am using Paypal API Keys for paypal and stripe api keys too for stripe.

```
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY=pk_test_51H3p40A7NfCMSQvjIG56zOW6IGEteTeSN30S7yRfsg05kV9qytDGqOGdSupb8ig4ck0VQ8hM3Hni4qeDgfgJE00gRTtKrfk
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=sk_test_51H3p40A7NfCMSQvjEMAQuQPlE7HeETEESF6qIzJGtCcK2wev5DkrQl6HABXCa9rSZRFvVCJYnSAEw4AhLeP1s3yl00zk7cwPHF

PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID=ED5iQei7CzF1KpZKNkA0d82VIascOGKsXad4GpzJX1bTh7R-scCQwk6dH_x4A6vBSlgun_xqN348Eiyo
PAYPAL_SECRET_KEY=AWWDqFrljs5QpZ8_8PumVRCYoWiGxoiMM_45lTL6JdbRT9VHA_qRtapSb-u66V3-A6mmvNoefnHfTxIb
```

So users will need to get above keys from their paypal and stripe accounts to accept payment.

However, is it possible to get API keys by having them to login to their account with email and password?

I think shopify doeos this as well.

In my shopify, I didn't put any api keys.

I just connected my paypal  & stripe accounts to shopify. So I was able to accept onetime & recurring payment.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a subscription where you pay, is different than processing payments on behalf of someone else.

To process PayPal subscriptions on behalf of someone else, they must have a business account, and they must create a REST API app and copy/paste its client ID and secret from the 'Live' tab of their applications view. They can log in here: https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications

Comment: Thanks, can't they just connect account and accept payment? I think stripe does it. Am I wrong?